# TabActivity listener with onCreate()

Tags: android, listener, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I have a project with two tabs. Tabs are created in the main class. Here I added the tablistener too, to handle the changes between the tabs. Here is one tab's instant:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();    
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_tab1))
                    .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

The listener method:

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {
    if (tabName.equals("tab1")){
        tab1.load();
    }
}
```

And similar for the second tab too. My question is, if the onCreate() methods run only once in the Tab1 and Tab2 classes, how can I "force" the main class to show the corresponding Activity after the tab changes? I receive NullPointerException

The tabs' classes are something like this:

```
    public class Tab1 extends Activity{
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
          super.onCreate(icicle);
          setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
          load();
      }
      public void load(){
        //....
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you're using Lists in both Tabs and want them to be re-populated each time you click then you will have to use this on onTabChanged() method. also I have implemented createTabContent(String s) of the TabHost.TabContentFactory interface to return different views(listviews in my case) depending on the tab on load of the app.

Comment: Where do you get null pointer exception? please specify the line.

Comment: It's ok now. The second tab wasn't added well. The onResume() method was the solution for my problem. Thanks you all:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onCreate()` method calls only once when your `Activity` first time loaded.

If you want to perform any functionality on each time you view your `Activity`, put that functionality in [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method.